# when i switch language some part of site is not translate in magento

Tags: magento, store, translate

in magento 1.9.2.4 I have two language: de, en.
de - is base language.
when i switch on the 'en' some part is not translate.

Where is a problem?

this is screenes of my debuging:
[image]
stores:
[image]

Comment: Check if those values are not affected by inline translation or if you have a translation CSV in your template folder, which will be prioritized.

Comment: Firstly I checked inline translation and csv translation. Translation table is empty, in csv we have a tranlate(you can see on the screen)

Comment: If you enable a inline-translation in Magento admin, you can inspect a source of the actual translation by icon showed near this element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem.
In Stores 'De' in menu configuration **General>Local Options>Locale** was English
[image]